# How to execute code on FrontEnd quit?

Tags: front-end

I would like to execute a block of code whenever the FrontEnd quits. I know about [`$Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Epilog.html), but it seems that this would execute every time the kernel quits, which is not what I want.  Does anyone know of any hooks into such functionality (perhaps by re-routing `FrontEndTokenExecute["FrontEndQuit"]` for instance)?

Thanks!

Comment: Theoretically this should be possible by setting the `$FrontEnd` Option `FrontEndEventActions` but I don't know the proper Event name for FrontEnd termination.

Comment: The following seems to work for when the session is killed through "Exit" in the File menu, but not for other ways of quitting (like clicking the close x at the upper right of your last notebook): SetOptions[$FrontEnd. FrontEndEventActions->{{"MenuCommand", "FrontEndQuit"} :> myCodeBlock, PassEventsDown -> True}].  I'd like something that works for all ways of quitting, but according to the docs, there don't seem to be any other relevant handles for FrontEndEventActions to act on :(.

Comment: How did you find `{"MenuCommand", "FrontEndQuit"}`?  I didn't even get that far.

Comment: In the docs for FrontEndEventActions, under "details", it says: "The possible event specifications are the same as for EventHandler, with the following addition: "WindowClose"".  Looking in the docs for EventHandler, you find the "MenuCommand" subset of possible events, and then searching the docs for "Menu Command" leads to the page on FrontEndTokens that lists "FrontEndQuit".  It's kind of convoluted, and in general I think that FrontEnd stuff is one place where the Mathematica docs are not so well done (compared to their excellent state elsewhere).

Comment: I also just want to re-emphasize the importance of the PassEventsDown->True bit... without it, myCodeBlock will execute, but the FrontEnd won't actually quit.

Comment: this idea is by far not a solution but at best a workaround: you could use the "WindowClose" event and check whether the closing notebook is the last notebook of the current the session. One problem I can see with this is that this might execute the code even if the user cancels the quit. There might be other problems as well (I haven't actually tried it)...